# How to iterate only once java stream

Tags: loops, java-8, stream

I have a data `Map<String, List<Students>>` where the key is the subject name.

I want to iterate through each subject and add the score of other subjects corresponding to a student.

I tried the follo

```
wing:

    data.entrySet().stream().forEach(subject -> sumScoresOfAStudent(subject, data));
    
    private void sumScoresOfAStudent(Entry<String, List<Student>> subject, Map<String, List<Student>> data) {
            String firstSubject = subject.getKey();
            List<Student> firstSubjectScores = subject.getValue();
            List<Student> otherSubjectScores = data.entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(subjectData -> !subjectData.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(firstSubject))
                    .map(subjectData -> subjectData.getValue()).flatMap(subjectData -> subjectData.stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            ...
        }
```

But here I noticed it would loop 3 times for the same data if I have 3 subjects as my Key. Is there any other better way to iterate it only once ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Eg:
        Student s11 = new Student("A", 20);
        Student s21 = new Student("B", 10);
        data.put("Maths", students);
        Student s12 = new Student("A", 30);
        Student s22 = new Student("B", 40);
        data.put("Science", students);
        Student s13 = new Student("A", 45);
        Student s23 = new Student("B", 20);
        data.put("History", students);

Expected Output :
Student A - 95
Student B - 70
```

Comment: So for `Map<String, List<Students>>`  is the key the subject and the list of students the students who are taking that subject?  Where does the score come in?  A  more specific example of before an after would be helpful (just of a subset though, not all your data).

Comment: Students class has score object -                                                                
 Student s11 = new Student("A", 51);
Student s21 = new Student("B", 51);

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I entirely misunderstood what you wanted. This presumes the Student class has the getters `getScore` and `getName`. This simply takes the `map values` which are `lists of students` and the flattens them into one large stream and computes the sum of each students score.

```
Map<String, Integer> scores =  data.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getName,
                Collectors.summingInt(Student::getScore)));

scores.forEach((name,score) -> System.out.printf("Student %s - %s%n", 
              name,score));
```

Prints

```
Student A - 95
Student B - 70
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a map of lists aka a *multimap* and it seems that you want to get the total scores per student. You could use a `Map<String, Integer>` for this, with the key being the student name and the value the total score.

Assuming `Student` has `getName()` and `getScore()` methods, here's a way to do what you want without streams:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
data.forEach((k, students) -> 
    students.forEach(s -> result.merge(s.getName(), s.getScore(), Integer::sum)));
```

This uses [`Map.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-), [`Iterable.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) and [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-). Check the docs to see how they work.

First, we are iterating the map. Then, for each entry `(k, students)` of the map, we iterate the values (which is a list of students). For each element `student` of the list, we put their name and score in the `result` map using the `Map.merge` method.

The `Map.merge` method works the same as `Map.put`, but if there's already an entry with the same key, it *merges* the present value with the new value using the 3rd argument (in this case `Integer::sum`) which, well, sums the old and new values for that key.

Answer (score 0):

I think your life would be easier if you first created a map of student to their subjects:

```
Map<Student, List<String>> studentSubjects = new HashMap<>();
data.forEach((k, v) -> v.forEach(studentSubjects.computeIfAbsent(v, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(k)));
```

But your “Student” class does not actually represent a student, but rather a student’s *result* for a subject. You should fix that too.